# Spring boot interceptor, intercept the problem of returning Chinese garbled characters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator

Spring boot interceptor, intercept the problem of returning Chinese garbled characters.

Code structure as shown

[image]

code show as below

demoFilter

```
public class demoFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    response.getWriter().write("您好");
    return;

  }
}
```

FilterConfig

```
@Configuration
public class FilterConfig {

  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean jwtFilter() {
    final FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new demoFilter());
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registrationBean;
  }

}
```

controller

```
@RestController
public class Demo {

  @RequestMapping(value = "demo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getStr(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return "demo";
  }
}
```

SpringApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Project start, visit http://localhost:8080/demo

Actual return:??

Expected return:您好

[image]

I added the following configuration to application.properties:

```
spring.http.encoding.force=true
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
```

Browser access, return:

[image]

Postman visits and returns correct results.

[image]

I would like to ask, how to solve this problem perfectly, so that the browser returns the correct Chinese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved, and the following code is added to solve the problem:

```java
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

[image]

[image]